# Import Google spreadsheet to another Google spreadsheet and preserve formatting

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I am trying to import information from one Google spreadsheet to another, but in the process I would like to keep the formatting from the source sheet.

I tried using `Importrange` function and while it worked to import the sheet it came as complete mess and didn't keep formatting from the source sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to go to your source sheet, click the arrow on the sheet tab, and select 'copy to'. In the popup box select the spreadsheet you want to copy the worksheet to and select it. That will copy the worksheet to the selected spreadsheet with the formatting. You could also do the copy with google apps script and retain the formatting.